# Testing the (complete) instantiation strategy of Z3

Tags: z3, smt

I am interested in testing the "practical" impact of the decision/instantiation procedure (its implementation inclusive) discussed in [1].

I need:

1) A "tool" that take an SMT benchmark and returns a (possibly complete) instantiated version of it, applying the strategy. If this is not possible,

2) The Z3 version implementing this strategy and an option for switching it on and off.

Can you help me on that?

[1] Complete Instantiation for Quantified Formulas in Satisfiabiliby Modulo Theories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no tool that will return the instantiated version of an SMT benchmark.
Z3 instantiates the quantifiers on-demand using Model-Based Quantifier Instantiation (MBQI) described on Section 6 of [1]. The actual loop in the latest Z3 is more complicated that the one described on this section.

Here are some notes on how to enable/disable the MBQI module.

- First, we should disable automatic configuration using the command

> (set-option :auto-config false)

- Z3 4.x uses MBQI and E-Matching for handling quantifiers. We should use the commands for disabling both of them:

> ```
> (set-option :ematching false)
> (set-option :mbqi false)
> ```

- To enable them, we should use:

> ```
> (set-option :ematching true)
> (set-option :mbqi true)
> ```

With these options you can check the effect of MBQI and E-Matching in different problems. Note that, if we use only E-matching, then Z3 will return `unknown` for any satisfiable problem that contains quantifiers.

The MBQI module is implemented in the files `src/smt/smt_model_finder.cpp` and `src/smt/smt_model_checker.cpp`. The file `src/smt/smt_model_finder.cpp` is essentially converting a model produced for the quantifier-free formulas in a model that may potentially satisfy the universally quantified formulas. Note that the class `auf_solver` is the one that actually "solves" the set constraints and "builds" the projection functions described in [1].

If we want to trace the actual instances generated by the MBQI module, we can modify the method `void model_checker::assert_new_instances()` at `src/smt/smt_model_checker.cpp`.  Note that these method already has some tracing commands sending data to `tout` (trace output). We can replace `tout` with `std::cout` to get the information on the standard output.
For example, if we add the following piece of code, then whenever a universal quantifier `q` is instantiated (by the MBQI module) with some bindings, Z3 will display the information in the standard output:

```c
std::cout << "[New-instance]\n" << mk_pp(q, m_manager) << "\n";
std::cout << "[Bindings]\n";
for (unsigned i = 0; i < num_decls; i++) {
    expr * b = inst->m_bindings[i];
    std::cout << mk_pp(b, m_manager) << "\n";
}
std::cout << "[End-New-Instance]\n";
```

Comment: @pad, how did you force language highlight without tagging the question as C++?

Comment: If you edit the answer, you will see a new line `<!-- language-all: c++ -->` added. See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting for reference.

Comment: Thanks a lot, and by the way, I think this is a great think that you made Z3-source available.

Comment: I searched (unsuccessfully) in (src/smt/smt_model_finder.cpp) for the (main) procedure, which solves the system of set constraints for the (S_{i,j})s. I am trying to implement a solver for constraints. Can you help me finding/using it. I am not the C++ expert :-)

Comment: In the paper the `i` in the set `S_{i,j}` is the quantifier id. In the implementation I use the (pointer to the) quantifier. I also used the structure `node` to store the sets and other information.  Given a quantifier `q` and its j-th variable, I use `s.get_uvar(q, j)` to retrieve the set (i.e., node) `S_{q,j)`. The pointer `m_find` is used to implement a union-find data-structure. That is, I perform the "union" of two sets by using method `merge`.

Comment: The actual solving is performed in two steps. First `process_auf` methods are invoked. These methods will create the nodes, and merge them when the sets represented by two needs must be equal. In the second step, `populate_inst_sets` methods are invoked to populate the sets corresponding to these nodes. Each "constraint" on the paper is represented by a subclass of `qinfo` and has a `process_auf` and `populate_inst_sets` method.